# SQL Help - Case/Exists Issue

Tags: sql, exists, having

Trying to join two tables together, I want to filter the select results based on a parameter in the first table and the second table. Having an issue in the not exists where I only want either the value when no value exists, or the custdef_id is one of two values, 13 or 15. So Having the exist does not select the data where the value does not exist, so trying a not exist condition to filter all stated custdef_id values of 20 and 21 but then it also cuts off the 15 value?

First query:

```
SELECT 
       BILL_NUMBER, 
       deliver_by_end, 
       actual_delivery, 
       c.custdef_id,
       (case when c.custdef_id = '13' then c.data end) "Late Flag",
       (case when c.custdef_id = '15' then c.data end) "Planned Late Flag"
       FROM TLORDER_all T LEFT join custom_data c on t.detail_line_id = c.src_table_key
WHERE 
       bill_number in ('T119633','T119634','T121374')
       AND DATE(T.DELIVER_BY) between :STARTDATE and :ENDDATE 
       and companY_id = '1'
       AND T.ACTUAL_DELIVERY IS NOT NULL 
       AND ((T.ACTUAL_DELIVERY > (T.DELIVER_BY_END + :MINUTESLATE MINUTES)  AND TIME(T.DELIVER_BY_END) <> '00:00:00') OR 
              ((TIME(T.DELIVER_BY_END)) = '00:00:00' AND T.ACTUAL_DELIVERY >= T.DELIVER_BY_END + 1 DAY)) 
order by 
       customer, bill_number
```

query results:

```
BILL_NUMBER           DELIVER_BY_END     ACTUAL_DELIVERY  CUSTDEF_ID Late Flag                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        Planned Late Flag                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
T119633               1/31/2023 23:59:00 2/3/2023 9:22:03 <null>     <null>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           <null>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
T119634               1/31/2023 23:59:00 2/6/2023 11:57:17 <null>     <null>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           <null>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
T121374               1/27/2023 1:30:00 1/27/2023 2:02:36         20 <null>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           <null>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
T121374               1/27/2023 1:30:00 1/27/2023 2:02:36         21 <null>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           <null>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
T121374               1/27/2023 1:30:00 1/27/2023 2:02:36         15 <null>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           Yes
```

I want the first two rows and last row. The repeating rows of 3 an 4 are pulling values I do not want. Tried a second query with a not exist of those CUSTDEF_ID of 20 and 21, and then I lose all but the first two rows?

```
SELECT 
       BILL_NUMBER, 
       deliver_by_end, 
       actual_delivery, 
       c.custdef_id,
       (case when c.custdef_id = '13' then c.data end) "Late Flag",
       (case when c.custdef_id = '15' then c.data end) "Planned Late Flag"
       FROM TLORDER_all T LEFT join custom_data c on t.detail_line_id = c.src_table_key
WHERE 
       not EXISTS(SELECT * FROM CUSTOM_DATA C WHERE T.DETAIL_LINE_ID = C.SRC_TABLE_KEY and C.custdef_id NOT in ('20','21') )
       and bill_number in ('T119633','T119634','T121374')
       AND DATE(T.DELIVER_BY) between :STARTDATE and :ENDDATE 
       and companY_id = '1'
       AND T.ACTUAL_DELIVERY IS NOT NULL 
       AND ((T.ACTUAL_DELIVERY > (T.DELIVER_BY_END + :MINUTESLATE MINUTES)  AND TIME(T.DELIVER_BY_END) <> '00:00:00') OR 
              ((TIME(T.DELIVER_BY_END)) = '00:00:00' AND T.ACTUAL_DELIVERY >= T.DELIVER_BY_END + 1 DAY)) 
order by 
       customer, bill_number
```

Results:

```
BILL_NUMBER           DELIVER_BY_END     ACTUAL_DELIVERY  CUSTDEF_ID Late Flag                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        Planned Late Flag                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
T119633               1/31/2023 23:59:00 2/3/2023 9:22:03 <null>     <null>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           <null>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
T119634               1/31/2023 23:59:00 2/6/2023 11:57:17 <null>     <null>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           <null>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using NOT IN inside a NOT EXISTS might be tripping you up, but it's hard to say exactly as we cannot see the DETAIL_LINE_ID value.

Why not simply use:

`WHERE (CUSTDEF_ID IS NULL OR CUSTDEF_ID IN ('13','15'))`

Comment: that worked, thank you! Needed some help seeing the forest through the trees I suppose.